# JSONExeption no value for

Tags: android, json

i have string object:

`String qwe =
 "{\"myObj\":"
+ "{"
+ "\"first\":123,"
+ "\"second\":111.0}"
+"}";`

And my code

```
private static final String TAG_FIRST = "first";
res = new JSONObject(qwe);
Double q1 = res.getDouble(TAG_FIRST);
```

I have exeption "no value for first".

What i doing wrong?

ps sorry for my bad english.
best regards

Comment: in addition to T.J. Crowder's answer: here you can check if the resulting `JSON` is valid when creating more complex objects http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON defines an object with the property `myObj`. The value of `myObj` is a different object. *That* object has a `first` property. This may be clearer if we look at just the JSON, and use indentation:

```
{
    "myObj": {
        "first": 123,
        "second": 111.0
    }
}
```

So first you have to get the `myObj` object, then get `first` from *it*.

```
private static final String TAG_MYOBJ = "myObj";
private static final String TAG_FIRST = "first";
res = new JSONObject(qwe);
JSONObject myObj = res.getJSONObject(TAG_MYOBJ);
Double q1 = myObj.getDouble(TAG_FIRST);
```

Alternately, if you didn't mean to have that outer layer, you may want your JSON string to look like this:

```
String qwe =
+ "{"
+ "\"first\":123,"
+ "\"second\":111.0"
+"}";
```

That string contains this JSON:

```
{
    "first": 123,
    "second": 111.0
}
```

...which would work correctly with your original code (duplicated here):

```
private static final String TAG_FIRST = "first";
res = new JSONObject(qwe);
Double q1 = res.getDouble(TAG_FIRST);
```